# I want to add a table or table row to a cartesian join and refresh. But I don't want the order of the rows to change

Tags: excel, cartesian

I have joined 8 tables with a cartesian join in excel. I want to record business rules against each row. I anticipate we may discover that we need a new variable and need to add another table or another row to an existing table and refresh the cartesian join. How can I maintain the relationship to the rules already captured? When I try this,  the cartesian join refresh causes the rows of business rules to loose the relationship to their original row as the new rows get inserted into the final table rather than appended.

Answer (score 0):

Add an ID column 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 etc. and then sort by ID

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).